# Search value from json in sqlite - Android

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite, android-room

I have table named User contain column named userDetails. userDetails column having data in json format like below.

```
{
    "id": "77",
    "uid": "247",
    "email": "abc@xyz.com",
}
```

How to query like 'where uid = 247' which is present in this json object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the column `userDetails` is a valid JSON string, you can use the function [`json_extract()`](https://www.sqlite.org/json1.html#the_json_extract_function):

```
select * 
from user
where json_extract(userDetails, '$.uid') = '247'
```

If you can't use SQLite's JSON1 extension, you can do it by treating `userDetails` as a normal string and use the operator `LIKE`:

```
select * 
from user
where ',' || replace(replace(replace(userDetails, '{', ''), '}', ''), ' ', '') || ',' like '%,"uid":"' || '247' ||'",%'
```

Replace the `?` placeholder with the id you search for, like `'247'`.

See a simplified [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=6249e4d31c6cad59efe4ce24d0edb19b).

Comment: works fine with DB browser..but when I used this in android, getting this error:
Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such function: json_extract (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR): , while compiling.

Comment: @PoyyamozhiRamakrishnan see my edited answer.

Comment: while this seems to be work around, I would like to know why i cant use JSON1 extension in android and how to use it ?

Comment: As you read from: https://www.sqlite.org/json1.html : *The json1 extension is a loadable extension...*, so it seems that it is not included in SQLite used in Android. Maybe you can do it with 3d party libraries. I found this: https://github.com/requery/sqlite-android

Comment: thank you for your time.. @forpas.. 3rd party library works fine.

Comment: @forpas what if it's array of json object?(i.e "userDetailies = {"contents":"4", "detail":[{"user":"john", "id":333,"phone#":2233"}] } and I'd like to print only the "phone#" is there a way if doing so without json_extract or 3rd lib? thanx in advance.

Comment: @hadeelKh With SQLite your only option is JSON1 Extension, so you need json_extract(): https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=bfa6090b4654e12ee348f0969db7cc91

Comment: but I can't use it with C++ language.. I've been trying to query json_extract() using sqlite3 lib inside cpp, I got "no such function json_extract()". I can use it perfectly in sqlitedb Browser though.

Comment: @hadeelKh I can't help you with cpp. Post a question where you explain what you want.